# Set Android output audio sampling rate

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, resampling

I'm trying to capture the system output audio data of Android. Now I implement it by modifying the codes in AudioFlinger. I'm able to capture it and write it to a file. And it works well. But the encoder I am asked to use only supports 48kHz, while the AudioFlinger gives me 44100Hz data. Is there any way that I can set the sampling frequency to 48KHz in Android.

Comment: On devices with Android 4.0 and later you should find a file named `audio_policy.conf` in `/system/etc/`. You could try removing 44100 as a supported sample rate for all outputs there, though you might end up breaking some use-case by doing that (e.g. there could be audio effects that expect to get 44100 Hz data).

Comment: It might be a way. But not a decent way. I'm afraid it would affect most of the app running on the system. The game will not give any audio anymore?